# How Can I show keyboard appears on label touch in tableview( iphone)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, label

I work on one application now I need some label on tableview cell and when user tap on that label then keyboard will show how we do that can some one tell me.I searched but every where they use notification i dont want that.

thanks

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:                       

 (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
            autorelease];
  }
 cell.textLabel.text=[Players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 playername=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 100, 30)];  
 playername.placeholder=@"Player";
 playername.delegate=self;
 playername.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
 playername.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
 [cell.contentView addSubview:playername];


 cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
 return cell;

 }
```

Comment: so the item inside your tableview cell is an editable UITextField and not an un-editable UILabel, *right*?

Comment: Yes michael you are right that label is editable.

Comment: @vishiphone: if this _label_ is editable then it's a UITextField and not a UILabel?

Comment: Thanks I will use textfield only now but I have some problem thats why I have remove textfield now I use textfield only.Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's strange in your app that do not use a UITextField or UITextView

but if you want this you may create a invisible UITextField or UITextView to show the keyboard

```
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[self.view addSubview:tf];
[tf becomeFirstResponder];
```

so you can handle the input use UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: I used textfield before but I also want to move to next view when user tap on table cell so if user again tap on cell.

Comment: :)  i don't quite understand what you described...   what the action you really want?

Comment: Adali I created a tableview in that tableview I created one textfield dynamically when user tap on textfield keyboard will appears and user can type his name on there but after type when user next time tap on that cell or textfield its move to next viewcontroller so then I want textfield disable editing and keyboard is not appears at second tap on cell.sorry for bad english.

Comment: so you just detect the second tap & disable the textfield  & resignFirstResponder ,  is that not enough?